# Kinetic Energy and a force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

An object is moving at a constant velocity

mass $m = 5 kg$
velocity $v = 20m/s$
Kinetic energy $K = 1000 joules$

If I divide $K$ by the distance traveled in *1sec* I get a force $f=50N$
What is this force?

Comment: A hint: $W=F\cdot x$

Comment: A hint: Constant velocity means net force = 0

Comment: Another hint: The force found is not being exerted right now. Also, think of the work-energy theorem: $W=\Delta K$.

Comment: Do you have an answer? or hints only?

Comment: Excuse me? I hope you are seeking an understanding of this and not just a homework-answer.

Comment: Why would you do that division? It doesn't make sense. If you take the momentum and divide by 1 s  you get 100 N, but that doesn't make sense either.  Answer: It's **not** a force. It merely has force units.

Comment: So this force is just a "nothing"?

Comment: Steeven, I think that answers the moment back in timeline when something moved the object, not a current moment where it's moving at a constant rate

Comment: Energy divided by time is not force, as others have said. Also, what do you mean by "What is this force?"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An object is moving at a constant velocity: mass m=5kg, velocity v=20m/s. If I divide K (the kinetic energy) by the distance traveled in 1 sec I get a force f=50N
>   What is this force?

If the body is moving in a vacuum you can interpret your mysterious force as the force needed to stop the body in $d=20 m$.

You find the force solving the equation: $mv^2/2 = F d$, where $F d$ is the mechanical work done by the force to stop the body.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more information is needed - but let me here assume that the object was once at rest.

Something made it start moving. That is, a force has done work on it. The energy-work theorem says that the work done on it equals the gain in kinetic energy (that would be $K$ in this case):

$$W=\Delta K=K$$

And the work is found from

$$W=\int \vec F\cdot d\vec r\approx Fx$$

So quite simply, if this is the setup, then the force you find by dividing with the distance travelled in $1$ second is the **resulting force that was originally done** (over that distance) **on it to give it it's current speed**:

$$W=Fx=K\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad F=K/x$$

Your distance seems to be chosen randomly, though, in which case this calculation really makes no sense.